# Where can I find an image for the location of the cold start injector on a 1996 Toyota Corolla DX?

Tags: toyota, corolla

Where can I find an image for the location of the cold start injector on a 1996 Toyota Corolla DX?

I cannot seem to find it on the engine and my googling seems fruitless.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better served by just asking: "Where is the cold start injector on my 96 Corolla?"

Comment: @Paulster2 perhaps, but rather than a long description and image is worth a 1000 words 

Comment: I get that and not my point, which is, instead of asking where to find an image, why not just ask for one to be presented here. "Where is the cold start injector? Can you show me an image?"

Comment: You would be well served to obtain a repair manual for the vehicle.  One possible option is Haynes Manual 3259 - Toyota Corolla Aug 1992 - 1997 Service and Repair Manual.

Comment: @Paul thanks for the advice. Where is the cold start injector? Can you show me an image?

Comment: I can find no "cold start injector" for your model, cold start is controlled by the pcm and fuel injectors.

Comment: @Moab that would explain it! I have been troubleshooting a challenge facing with the corolla (will not start when below 40F, so far replaced all the plugs and wires, fuel pump, engine coolant temperature sensor, battery is solid, as is the distributor cap and it starts first turn and run great ... As long as the temperature is above 40F). It was suggested that I check the cold start injectior. Now I am not sure what to try next!